# How can I loop through a data structure?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, dictionary

I have following data structure in Python. The problem is that when I am using `for` loop to iterate over it, it gives me type error. Data structure is as follows:

```
{'property': 154, 'url': 'https://factopedia.org'}
{'property': 151, 'url': 'https://api.factopedia.org'}
```

It has two items, and every item has a key value pair.

I am using following code to iterate it and assigning it to a different structure:

```
for link in links:
    payload[f'Links[{links["property"]}][url]'] = link['url']
```

Error is:

```
  payload[f'Links[{links["property"]}][url]'] = link['url']
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I iterate the structure and get values for property and url?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in order to receive help

Comment: apologies for not providing minimal reproducible example. I am actually debugging a large code implemented with a class, so being a newbie in python I cant produce the running code. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: " I am actually debugging a large code implemented with a class"  - that's why you need to make an effort to create the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should just be a couple of small typos. First, your second line looks like it should be indented, and where you have `links["property"]`, it looks like you would want `link["property"]`.

```py
for link in links:
    payload[f'Links[{link["property"]}][url]'] = link['url']
```

The reason it is giving you that error is that you are trying to get the `"property"` attribute of links, which is some iterable data structure like a list, and you would index those with an integer (`links[3]`) or slice (`links[1:]`) for example.